# analytic solution to elliptic PDE in R^n

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, elliptic-pde, analytic-functions

I am looking for (minimal) conditions, which guarantee that the problem

Lu = 0 in R^n,

where L is a second-order (uniformly) elliptic operator with analytic coefficients, has a unique global analytic solution. Does anybody have any references to relevant work?

Comment: As Liviu indicates, $u = 0$ is already a solution, so your question is equivalent to asking what conditions imply that $u = 0$ is the only solution. I don't know the answer to this, but one possible approach is to write an arbitrary solution as a power series and study whether there are identifiable conditions on $L$ that force the radius of convergence to be finite.

Answer (score 2):

When $L$ has analytic coefficients, any solution of $Lu=0$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$ is automatically analytic. You should be asking  about conditions guaranteeing that the only solution of this equation is $u=0$.  For example, if you assume that  $u(x)\to 0$ as $|x|\to \infty$, then the maximum principle will do the trick. For more refined  results you could try a Gooogle search or a MathSciNet search.